Catch message not being hit? ZSH abort
I am practicing exceptions and wanted to force an std::out_of_range. For some reason I am either not hitting the catch or it is not giving me the std::cerr output.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    try {
        std::vector<int> numbers{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        std::cout << numbers.at(numbers.size()) << std::endl;

    } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
        std::cerr << "Something failed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Something failed" << std::endl;
    }
}

The terminal responds with
zsh: abort      "/...path/to/file/"filename

What does this mean? This only seems to be the case with using g++-13 on Mac from homebrew. Using g++ (apple clang alias) correctly gives me Something failed: vector . Is something happening behind the scenes with the compiler that prevents the std::cerr from being executed?

Wild guess: linking with the wrong libraries.

Cannot reproduce on my mac. g++-13 gives "Something failed: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 9) >= this->size() (which is 9)"

What call are you using to compile this? How do you call the compiled program?

Good thought @UlrichEckhardt, I was actually able to fix this by removing --std=c++23 but I am not sure why it mattered, and mainly just curious what is going on.
g++-13 --std=c++23 exceptions.cpp is what I was using.
